# Minimum eigenvalue of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_iv_i^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^d, 1\le i \le n.$ I was wondering whether we can find/express the **minimum eigenvalue** of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_iv_i^{T}$ as  function of the vectors $v_i?$ If an equality isn't possible can we have something like the minimum eigenvalue of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_iv_i^{T} \ge f(v_1, \dots v_n)?$

If we try to use that the minimum eigenvalue of the sum of real symmetric matrices is at least the sum of the minimum eigenvalues of the matrices, [as stated and answered in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718559/lower-bound-on-the-minimum-eigenvalue-of-sum-of-two-matrices), this is not of help, as each $v_iv_i^{T}$ has minimum eigenvalue zero, being of rank one.

**Thanks to the comment by PhoemueX below:** for the minimum eigenvalue in the OP  is zero if we take $n < d$ by the following rank argument. Here we're adding $n$ number of $d \times d$ matrices of rank one, therefore the sum will have rank $ \le n < d.$ (using the fact that max eigenvalue of sum of symmetric matrices is less than or equal to sum of the max eigenvalues of the summands. So the sum in question is a $d \times d$ matrix, with rank at most $n < d.$ So the min eigenvalue is zero.

So this leaves the question open for the case $n \ge d$ only.

Comment: I'd first look at the problem with $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: If n < d, then this is easy (why?)

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, in that case, the we're adding $n$ number of $d \times d$ matrices of rank one, therefore the sum will have rank $ \le n$ (using the fact that max eigenvalue of sum of symmetric matrices is less than or equal to sum of the max eigenvalues of the summands. So the sum in question is a $d \times d$ matrix, with rank at most $n < d.$ So the min eigenvalue is zero.

Comment: @PhoemueX Adding the above bit to my OP, giving credit to your comment.

Comment: If the vectors $(v_i)$ are an ONB then the matrix is the identity.

Comment: The question is also what kind of function you are looking for. You could just take $f(v_1,...,v_n)$ to be "the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix ..." :D

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ denotes the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_n$, then you're looking for the eigenvalues of $VV^\top$, or equivalently the squares of the  singular values of $V$.

For $n < d$, the smallest eigenvalue is always $0$. For the remaining eigenvalues, it's more efficient to look at $V^\top V $, which is smaller but has the same non-zero eigenvalues as $VV^\top$.

For $n > d$, $V^\top V$ is a larger matrix so you're better off either considering the singular value decomposition of $V$ or considering the matrix $V V^\top$ directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if $v_1\dots v_n$ are all linearly independent, then we can say that $\sum_i v_iv_i^{T}$ is nonsingular (i.e. positive definite and symmetric) since $v_i= Ae_i$ for some basis change matrix $A$, and in this case, can we come up with a more simpliefied form of the minimum eigenvalue of the same, since we're really looking for the eigenvalue of the matrix $AA^{T}?$

Comment: The matrix that you're calling $A$ is exactly the matrix that I am calling $V$, assuming that $e_i$ refers to an element of the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$. There is no special formula for the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix $AA^T$, but there are methods for calculating (approximating) it numerically.

Comment: It might be a trivial observation, but for $n=d$ and $v_i$ linearly independent the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix $AA^T$ is the smallest number in the sequence $$M_1, M_2/M_1, M_3/M_2, ..., M_n/M_{n-1}$$ where $M_i$ is the $i$-th principal upper left minor of the matrix $AA^T$. You can thus compute this sequence and write down the smallest number in the sequence explicitly by applying absolute value $|\cdot|$ a lot ($\min(a,b) = \frac{1}{2}(|a+b| -|a-b|)$, $\min(a,b,c) = \min(\min(a,b),c)$, and so on).

Comment: But I imagine it's not a very satisfying answer, since the formula is pretty complicated (both for the sequence and for the minimum).

Comment: You can bound the smallest eigenvalue from below using Gershgorin circle theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem). It's an "optimal" lower bound in the sense that the bound is achieved for the smallest eigenvalue of some positive definite matrix (f.i. a diagonal matrix). But it's not usefull unless the matrix is diagonally dominant.

Comment: Here is another type of estimate: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652706/1145894