# For a.e. $x$ in convex hull of $\{x_1\dots x_n\}\subset R^d, \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x-x_i)(x-x_i)^{T}$ nonsingular,$\{x_1, \dots x_n\}$ spans $R^d, n \ge d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a question relevant to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630234/minimum-eigenvalue-of-sum-i-1nv-iv-it/4630353?noredirect=1#comment9794237_4630353).

Let $n \ge d, \{x_1 \dots x_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^d.$ Let $x$ be a point in the convex hull $C$ of $\{x_1 \dots x_n\}. $ Assume that  $\{x_1 \dots x_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ spans $\mathbb{R}^d.$ **EDIT:** assume, if necessary that the interior of the convex hull is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d.$ I was wondering if it's true that for almost every $x$ in the convex hull $C$ above:

$$f(x):=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x-x_i)(x-x_i)^{T}$$

is nonsingular or not?

If we take $d=1, f(x)$ is clearly non zero at every point. I'm trying to see if there's any generalization to this.

Comment: Are the vectors column vectors (so the transposed vectors are row vectors)? Is $f$ $d \times d$ sized matrix valued?

Comment: Every matrix in your sum is positive semi-definite. So now we just have to prove that there doesn't exist a nonzero vector $v$ such that $(x-x_i)^Tv = 0$ for every $i$.

Comment: And the last claim holds in the special case when the points $x_i$ are affinely independent (that is, when the convex hull is $d$ dimensional). So if "almost everywhere" means "up to a $\mathcal{L}^d$-measure zero set" then we are done.

Comment: But I might have made a mistake in my reasoning. Please double-check whether it's right.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your question is that $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ are fixed and $x$ is chosen "randomly" from the convex hull.
It is not entirely clear what "randomly" means, but I assume you mean uniformly distributed on $C$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $C$ in the corresponding dimension (but note that this dimension might be smaller than $d$).

If this interpretation is correct, then the answer is negative, here is a counterexample (inspired by the comments of Jkbb):

Consider $n=d=2$, $x_{1} = (-1,0)^{\top}$ and $x_{2} = (1,0)^{\top}$. Then, for any $x$ in the convex hull of $\{ x_{1}, x_{2} \}$ and for $v = (0,1)^{\top}$, we obtain:
$$
(x-x_{i})^{\top} v = 0,\qquad i=1,2,
$$
which implies $f(x) v = 0$.

It is easy to construct such examples for any $d,n$.
In fact, the most simple (but not very insightful) counterexample is to have $x_{i} = 0$ for each $i$, in which case $f(x)$ is the zero-matrix for any $x$ in the (trivial) convex hull.

However, if the points $x_{i}$ are random themselves, things might look very different, but then you really have to say what "random" means (which probability measure? independence? etc.).
But even then, I am pretty sure that you need $n \geq d+1$. For $n=d$ the convex hull will be at most $(d-1)$-dimensional and there will always be a vector $v$ perpendicular to all $(x-x_{i})$, so the above argument holds true (think of three non-collinear points in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$: the convex hull will be part of a plane, so there will be a vector perpendicular to that plane).

**UPDATE** after the question was edited and $C$ is assumed to contain a nontrivial open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ (note that this requires $n\geq d+1$):

Following the comments of Jkbb once again, note that $f(x) v =0$ would imply that
$$0 = v^{\top} f(x) v = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \|(x-x_{i})^{\top}v\|_{2}^{2}.$$
However, this implies that $v$ is perpendicular to *all* vectors $(x-x_{i})$, meaning that the span of these vectors is a genuine subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ (if it was equal to $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ there would not be a vector perpendicular to it).
This contradicts the assumption that $C$ contains a nontrivial open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ (the vectors $x_{i}$ must not lie in a hyperplane).

So $f(x)$ is nonsingular for every $x \in C$ (no probability theory or almost-sure-statements necessary).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid that I didn't express myself clearly, ideally I want my convex hull to have the same dimension as the ambient space, i.e. the interior of the compact, convex hull $C$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d.$ I wonder if we can say something then? And in this case, I'm talking about almost surely w.r.t. to the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. In my case, the $x_i$'s are all fixed, but it'd be a next step to randomly vary them later, but not now :)

Comment: Yes, if the vectors $x_{i}$ do not lie in a hyperplane (note that this requires $n\geq d+1$), then $f(x)$ is always nonsingular. I updated my answer. Minor comment: the empty set is also an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, so I added "nontrivial" in my update.

Comment: Thanks - I've still slight difficulty at this step: "This contradicts the assumption that $C$ contains a nontrivial open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$". I understand that you're connecting two statements: "$C$ contains a nontrivial open subset of $R^d$" and  for any given fixed  "$x\in C, x-x_i, 1\le i \le n$" are all linearly independent, and while intuitively it's clear, I'm having trouble connecting these two rigorously...

Comment: I also wonder if in this particular case where $C$ contains a nontrivial open subset of $R^d,$ is there a lower bound for the eigenvalues of $f(x)$ that we can establish - perhaps similar work has been done before.

Comment: Here the lower bound on the eigenvalue must be positive, as all the summand matrices are non-negative definite (rank one to be precise).

Comment: I agree that this step requires more rigor: Since $a_{i} = x_{i} - x$ span a subspace $U$ of dimension $\leq d-1$, then the vectors $x_{i} = x + a_{i}$ as well as their convex hull lie in the affine subspace $x+U$ of dimension $\leq d-1$, the interior of which is empty.

Comment: Concerning the bound on the eigenvalues, I have no good answer, but maybe the following consideration helps: If $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair of $f(x)$ with $\|v\|_{2}=1$, then $\lambda = v^{\top} (\lambda v) = v^{\top} f(x) v = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \|(x-x_{i})^{\top}v\|_{2}^{2}$, so we can definitely say that $\lambda \geq \inf_{v\colon \|v\|_{2}=1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \|(x-x_{i})^{\top}v\|_{2}^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, it's just that if the presence of $v$ in this lowerbound can be avoided, that'd be great. I see that here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480504/lower-bound-on-smallest-eigenvalue-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix, they stated a lower bound for all symmetric positive definite matrices - see the first answer, although most probably it won't be helpful, as it'll be too complicated...