# Projection to triangular matrices whose symmetrisation has positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, projection

Let $\lambda>0$, and $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the space of matrices equipped with Frobenius norm. Consider the set
$$
D=\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\mid \textrm{$A$ is lower triangular and eigenvalues of $A+A^*$ is larger or equal to $\lambda$ }\}. 
$$
Then  $D$ is nonempty, closed and convex   ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718559/lower-bound-on-the-minimum-eigenvalue-of-sum-of-two-matrices)).
Hence by the [Hilbert projection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem),
the  orthogonal projection (with respect to the Frobenius inner product)
$P: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to D$
is well-defined. That is,
for all $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,
$P(A)$ is defined as the unique element in $D$ such that
$$
 P(A)
=\arg\min_{B\in D}
 \|B-A\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}.
$$

May I know given $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$,
can $P(A)$
be computed analytically or numerically?

---

The question is  mainly motivated by optimising a nonlinear function over the set $D$, such as a quadratic function
$A\mapsto  \|A-C\|^2_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}$ with a given matrix $C$.
The first  method came to my mind would be a projected gradient method, which requires to compute the projection.
Projection to the space of lower triangular matrices is easy, but  it is unclear how to handle it together with the constraints on eigenvalues of the symmetric part of $A$.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks for your comment. The projection map can always be defined as long as $D$ is non-empty closed convex by [Hilbert projection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem). The map $P$ may not be linear if $D$ is not a subspace. In particular, $P(\boldsymbol{0})$ will be the unique element in $D$, such that $\|P(\boldsymbol{0})\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}\le \|A\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}$ for all $A\in D$. I will recall this definition in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rephrasing slightly, let

$$ \mathcal{D}_{\mu}^n := \left\{ {\bf X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \mid {\bf X} \textrm{ is lower triangular and } {\bf X} + {\bf X}^\top \succeq \mu {\bf I}_n \right\}$$

Thus, we can project a given matrix ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ onto $\mathcal{D}_{\mu}^n$ as follows

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {{\bf X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} {\text{minimize}} & \| {\bf X} - {\bf A} \|_{\text{F}}^2 \\ \text{subject to} & x_{ij} = 0, \quad \forall j > i\\ & {\bf X} + {\bf X}^\top \succeq \mu {\bf I}_n \end{array} $$

Comment: I understand this is an equivalent formulation. May you elaborate further how to solve this constrained optimization problem? Do you suggest solving analytically or numerically it by some iterative methods?

Comment: Both Matlab and Python are fine. I have never used the function you mentioned, but I will have a look.

Comment: Which function? Do you need to get a numerical solution very fast? If not, CVX or CVXPY should be fine for a start

Comment: May you kindly include a sample code to show how to incorporate the element wise and eigenvalue constraints in the CVX/CVXPY implementation?

Comment: @John I don't have a working version of CVXPY in my machine anymore. The equality constraints would be something like `X[i,j] == 0` and $\succeq$ might be [`>>`](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#semidefinite-matrices).  If you search for `user:339790 cvxpy` on Mathematics SE, you can find CVXPY code I have posted before — most of which is now obsolete, I assume.

Comment: @John Have you tried numerical experiments?

Comment: Yes. I did implement the algorithm with cvxpy. The triangular constraint is implemented with upper_tri function. It solves a 100 by 100 minimization problem using around 1 minute. It is not ideal but suffices for my current application.

Comment: Do you have any idea on improving the algorithm efficiency? Can I directly optimize over lower triangular matrices, instead of over dense matrix with additional triangular constraints? It should reduce the number of unknown variables by half, and remove all element-wise constraints.

Comment: @John What if one used the matrix ${\bf Y} := {\bf X} + {\bf X}^\top$ instead?  Then, one would apply a "mask" to $\bf Y$ (with $0$ above the main diagonal, $\frac12$ on the main diagonal and $1$ below the main diagonal) using the entry-wise product to make it lower-triangular, then subtract $\bf A$.

Comment: @John Alternatively, one could work with the $\binom{n+1}{2}$ relevant entries of the lower triangular matrix.  No need for equality constraints anymore

Comment: @John You can also post your code on Stack Overflow, link to this question, and request advice on how to speed it up

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just for your information, the reformulation with $Y= X+X^\top$ reduces a computational time by a factor of 10 (for 100 by 100 matrix)! I guess this is due to the fact that I can specify $Y$ as a symmetric matrix, and cvxpy uses a more efficient solver for the resulting semidefinite programming. I am satisfied with the current algorithm performance, and will consider post it on Stack Overflow if further refinement is needed.

Comment: @John I am happy to hear that!  One order of magnitude is always something to celebrate!